# Alternative to xeditable for Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ngx-inline-editor, the problem is that I need an onshow event, an event that fires up when I click the field(select), ngx-inline-editor doesn't have this, I tried using onclick but I have to click twice for the options, which are taken from a database, to update.

Does anyone know how to implement xeditable to angular 2+ projects? or maybe there's a way to add an onshow event to ngx-inline-editor?

I can't load up the options beforehand because the options depend on which field I click, basically I grab a bunch of cars from a database, and you can modify the "state" of each car, but the states you can select depends on another variable of the car, so I need an onshow event to load up the options, and then also set the starting option to the current state.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute a function when the DOM element is visible on viewport, you can use one of this plugins

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-inview
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-viewport

Or maybe use some alternative events:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0

hope this help you :D

Comment: I get the following error when I add angular2-viewport: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable', I am already importing Observable from rxjs.

Comment: maybe this help: https://victorroblesweb.es/2018/05/25/solucion-a-los-errores-con-rxjs-en-angular-6/

Comment: That fixed the other error, but now the problem I am having is that angular is not recognizing angular2-viewport as a module, unfortunately I think the module is very out of date, I'm going to look for alternatives.